# How to downgrade to gcc 7.3?

Tags: nvidia, compiling, 19.10, gcc, cuda

I am Ubuntu 19.10, and I wanted to install CUDA on it. But I am hampered by the 'gcc' version on my OS. CUDA can't use gcc 9 (supported version [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html))

So, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846467/how-can-i-install-gcc-7-3-for-ubuntu-16-04) answer, I managed to download the .deb file of gcc 7.4 and used this command:-

```
sudo dpkg -i gcc-7-base_7.4.0-6_amd64.deb
```

to run and compile the file. It just gave a warning about downgrading and went on anyway. However, on running this command==>

```
gcc --version
```

I got version 9.3, the version I wanted to downgrade from. I had positively uninstalled using the command `sudo apt remove gcc` but am dumbstruck why it is still 9.3. Any help?

> **P.S=>** I am an absolute noob at ubuntu, so please be a little patient with me. Also note that I have both 10.1 and 10.2 CUDA version downloaded, so please advise me accordingly

Comment: What does `gcc-7 --version` say? usually, the issue is that `/usr/bin/gcc` is a symbolic link that is created during installation of the default `gcc` pacakge

Comment: @steeldriver Wow! gcc-7 does tell version 7.5, But would it be able to use CUDA? coz it requires 7.3.....

Comment: @steeldriver As told before, I am a noob. Could you explain in a bit more simple way, or link me through some tutorials?

Comment: But the problem is far from solved. It has now messed up with my display...

Comment: I deleted my comment because I realised that it's unlikely to help now that you took the step of manually installing an out-of-repo version of gcc-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mechanisms in place to switch the version of gcc (and other tools) you get with using their name (gcc), See the update-alternatives man page, but there are recommendations that changing the system-wide gcc default is a bad thing.  Another way, which meets your needs without altering the system-wide defaults is to add the gcc ( and ar, nm, ranlib) links to the desired version into your cuda bin directory, which you should have been placed before the system parts in your PATH. 
I just did this for gcc-5 on an older CUDA in 18.04,  with that limit, and it worked.

Comment: I actually did this by changing gcc version priority and then running CUDA, but I guess your answer is the closest, so I am marking it answer...